# Is adding a css class to a <b> tag valid html/css

Tags: html, css

**Is adding a css class to a `<b>` tag valid html/css**

Example, can I do this:

```
<b class="myclass"> Foo Bar </b>
```

Is this valid html/css?

I need to add a class to a `b` tag as an identifier so I can use it in jQuery/js. It wont have any css styles

Comment: There's nothing wrong with IMHO

Comment: "It is a good practice to use the class attribute on the `<b>` in order to convey additional semantic information (for example `<b class="lede">` for the first sentence in a paragraph). This eases the development of several stylings of a web document, without the need to change its HTML code." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/b

Comment: If it's an _identifier_ maybe it should be an `id` not a `class`. A class is appropriate if there are several things on the page that are all `myclass` and you want to style or select them all. There are other ways to use jQuery (or CSS) selectors that may be more appropriate, such as `$(".article > p > b")` to select all `b` in a paragraph within an article, without having to give each element its own class.  It all depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**, [b](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element) tag can have all [global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#global-attributes), including `class`.
The full list of attributes, you can add to `b` element:

- accesskey
- class
- contenteditable
- contextmenu
- dir
- draggable
- dropzone
- hidden
- id
- inert
- itemid
- itemprop
- itemref
- itemscope
- itemtype
- lang
- spellcheck
- style
- tabindex
- title
- translate

You can also use any [custom data attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#custom-data-attribute).

Finally, you can add also ARIA [`role`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/dom.html#aria-role-attribute) attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Of course. There's nothing wrong with that.

However, it's generally a bad idea to use `class` *purely* for identifying an element. Consider using something like `data-reference` or something, as this will be more correct (and more efficient on the browser not having to keep track of a class that's not used as a class)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is perfectly valid. Absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing strictly wrong with it, except that the `<b>` bold tag is deprecated, in favor of using the `<strong>` tag.

I never give the strong (or b) tag a class because I only use it when I want the text **strong** to call attention to it, similar to `<em>` *emphasizing* words in text.

If I am bolding or emphasizing the text for some other reason I use a div or span with a class — for example, it is common to italicize the title of a book or article, and in that case I do not use `<em>` around the title, I use `<span class="title">This Is That Title</span>` to semantically mark *what* this thing is, then use a stylesheet to say "titles are italic".

Comment: HTML5 redefines b, i, strong, and em — see the link provided by Luke Rehmann in the comment on Billy Moat's answer.  I still tend to avoid b and i

Answer (score 0):

There are no “CSS classes”. CSS has class selectors, but that’s a different issue and *postulates* the existence of a `class` attribute in a markup language. Thus, the question is meaningless as far as CSS is considered.

In HTML, the `class` attribute is valid (formally correct) on `b` elements, in any HTML version from HTML 4.0 (which introduced the attribute) onwards. Whether it makes sense or not is a different issue, but there are no formal restrictions on its use. Although `class` is most often used for styling, it can be used for other purposes, too, especially in scripting.